# C++ Client Proxy header file not generated by soapcpp2.exe in gSoap

Tags: c++, gsoap

After successfully run wsdl2h.exe which generate a header file 'calc.h', which is as below-

```
C:\Users\Tushar\Desktop\gsoap_2.8.22\gsoap-2.8\gsoap\bin\win32>wsdl2h -o calc.h calc.wsdl

**  The gSOAP WSDL/Schema processor for C and C++, wsdl2h release 2.8.22
**  Copyright (C) 2000-2015 Robert van Engelen, Genivia Inc.
**  All Rights Reserved. This product is provided "as is", without any warranty.

**  The wsdl2h tool is released under one of the following licenses:
**  GPL or the commercial license by Genivia Inc. Use option -l for details.
Saving calc.h

Cannot open file "typemap.dat"
Problem reading type map file 'typemap.dat'.
Using internal type definitions for C++ instead.


Reading file 'calc.wsdl'...
Done reading 'calc.wsdl'

To complete the process, compile with:

> soapcpp2 calc.h
or to generate C++ proxy and object classes:
> soapcpp2 -j calc.h
```

Next, I have run the gSOAP compiler 'soapcpp2' on the gSOAP header file 'calc.h' to produce the source code stub and skeleton to implement the client application. which is as follows-

```
C:\Users\Tushar\Desktop\gsoap_2.8.22\gsoap-2.8\gsoap\bin\win32>soapcpp2 -IC:\Users\Tushar\Desktop\gsoap_2.8.22\gsoap-2.8\gsoap\import  calc.h

**  The gSOAP code generator for C and C++, soapcpp2 release 2.8.22
**  Copyright (C) 2000-2015, Robert van Engelen, Genivia Inc.
**  All Rights Reserved. This product is provided "as is", without any warranty.

**  The soapcpp2 tool is released under one of the following licenses:
**  GPL or the commercial license by Genivia Inc.

Saving soapStub.h annotated copy of the source input
Saving soapH.h declarations to #include
Using ns1 service name: calc
Using ns1 service style: document
Using ns1 service encoding: literal
Using ns1 service location: localhost:8000
Using ns1 schema namespace: urn:calc/calc.wsdl
Saving calc.add.req.xml sample SOAP/XML request
Saving calc.add.res.xml sample SOAP/XML response
Saving calc.sub.req.xml sample SOAP/XML request
Saving calc.sub.res.xml sample SOAP/XML response
Saving calc.mul.req.xml sample SOAP/XML request
Saving calc.mul.res.xml sample SOAP/XML response
Saving calc.div.req.xml sample SOAP/XML request
Saving calc.div.res.xml sample SOAP/XML response
Saving calc.nsmap namespace mapping table
Saving soapClient.cpp client calling stubs
Saving soapClientLib.cpp client stubs with serializers (use only for libs)
Saving soapServer.cpp server request dispatcher
Saving soapServerLib.cpp server request dispatcher with serializers (use only for libs)
Saving soapC.cpp serializers

Compilation successful
```

since in gSoap documentation has written that, Proxy classes for C++ client applications are automatically generated by the gSOAP soapcpp2 tool.

But there is no proxy file in above code?.. what i have done wrong here, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate proxy classes use soapcpp2.exe with -j tag.